# Extend Container behind bottom navigation flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to extend the white container behind the bottom navigation bar to the very end of the screen. Not just to the limit of the botton navigation bar (as you can see in the picture).

[image]

Any help or idea is really appreciated, I am quite new in Flutter. Thanks!

The structure of the app is:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    notchMargin: 8.0,
    child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.show_chart,
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 48.0),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.filter_list,
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
        height: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
            topRight: Radius.circular(40)
          )
        ),
      ),
      )
    ],
  )
```

Comment: how did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can use "extendBody: true" inside "Scaffold" class

```dart
Scaffold(
    extendBody: true,
    body: _yourBody(),
    bottomNavigationBar: _yourBottomNavBar(),
)
```

Answer (score -2):

Set `backgroundColor` value to `Colors.white` as well in `Scaffold`

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      ....
      ....
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Only works if nothing is display on screen